# vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker - append datetimepicker field with custom text

Tags: datetimepicker, bootstrap-vue, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to customize the date time picker field. I am trying to append or add a suffix to the time.

**My Code:**

```
<date-picker v-model="time" class="portal-time-picker" placeholder="Pickup Time" 
  :leg.timeEntered="false" @input="timeEntered = true" 
  :config="{format: 'LT',widgetPositioning: {horizontal:'auto',vertical:'top'}}" required @dp- 
  change=" setUTCDate">
</date-picker>
```

**Visual Representation of What I want:**
[image]

**Things I have tried:**

1.

```
<template v-slot:default="{ value }">
  <input type="text" 
    :value="value + ' ' + Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone"
    placeholder="Pickup Time (timezone)" readonly>    
</template>
```

2. 

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-datepicker v-model="date" :append="suffix"></b-form-datepicker>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      date: null,
      suffix: ' (UTC)'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For now I have done something temporary.

**Changes:**
[image]

**Visually:**

[image]

**but I still want timezone inside the field, Need help with that**.